# How to put Python list with Flask into a HTML select options?

Tags: python, html, flask

So, let's say that I have this list written on my main Flask app:

```
calculations = ['Summary', 'Average', 'Minimal Value', 'Maximum Value', 'Median', 'Count', 'Standard Deviation']
```

I have a template which goes like this:

```
@app.route('/analyze.html')
def analyze():
    return render_template('analyze.html', name=calculations)
```

And on the template, I wrote:

```
<select class="form-control" name="calculations">
    {% for calc in calculations %}
        <option value="{{ calc }}">{{ calc }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I want to show the `calculations` list into the select options on the HTML template so it can chooses one of the calculations. When I tried this way, it displayed nothing on the option list.

How should i do this?

Comment: Don't you mean `calculations=calculations`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're assigning the list to a variable named 'name' in the route.
You should change

```
return render_template('analyze.html', name=calculations)
```

to be

```
return render_template('analyze.html', calculations=calculations)
```

Comment: Omg, I didn't notice it before. This is the kind of error i hate. Thanks!